# How do I change the Node.js Version when using glitch.com

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, version, discord

For the past 1 hour I have been setting up my discord.js bot on glitch.com. But whenever I run it shows this. `const init = async () => {
                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` I remember a couple of months back I asked what that meant. And it (basically) you need to update node. But since I am on glitch.com, the only option it gives me is to put it in the package.json. So i did.I used this example package.json

`"engines": { "node": "8.4.0" },`

And It still doesn't change from v6.11.4 to v8.4.0 as I wanted it to. Please help.